# How can I get the data from all entries?

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I wrote a def to create an n*n matrix with entries. I want to get the inputed data from all of the entries but I always got only the last one.

```
from tkinter import *

import numpy as np

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x300')
root.title('PythonExamples.org - Tkinter Example')

global e1
global numm
global my_entry
entries=[]
my_entry= Entry(root)
e1=Entry(root)
e1.place(x=200,y=100)



def create():
    numm=int(e1.get())
    global my_entry
    for x in range(numm):
        for i in range(numm):
            my_entry = Entry(root)
            my_entry.grid(row=x, column=i)
            entries.append(my_entry)

def save():
    for entry in entries:
        my_array=entry.get()
    print(my_array)






create= Button(root,text='Submit',command=create).place(x=40,y=180)
save= Button(root,text='Save',command=save).place(x=40,y=210)

my_label=Label(root,text='')
root.mainloop()
```

How can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give us a reproducible code? Here I am able to create a list, run a method adding elements to that list and keep the added elements once the method is exited. I think I'd need some more information to investigate further

Comment: How can I do that?( Sorry I don't know what reproducible code is)

Comment: A reproducible code is the minimum code needed to reproduce the error/problem that you are encountering. For instance you've omitted here that `Entry` was coming from an import from Tkinter. Thus someone else could not have copy pasted your code into an editor, run it, verify the issue, and investigate. If it really is too hard to isolate the problematic part, you may want to share the entirety of the code (if not too long, if it is you won't have a choice but isolate the part).

Comment: Sure, I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `save` function loops over the list of entry widgets, but throws away every value but the last. If you want to print out each value, move the print statement inside the loop. If you want to create an array with all of the values, append each value to a list.

```
def save():
    my_array = []
    for entry in entries:
        my_array.append(entry.get())
    print(my_array)
```

Though, that loop can be condensed into a list comprehension:

```
def save():
    my_array = [entry.get() for entry in entries]
    print(my_array)
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want, thank you !